# Discord API 401 Unauthorized with OAuth

Tags: python, api, oauth, discord

Quick question: I'm trying to use the Discord API to make a backup of all the messages on a server (or a guild, if you use the *official* term).

So I implemented OAuth without any problems, I have my access token and I can query some endpoints (I tried `/users/@me`, `/users/@me/guilds`). Though, most of them don't work. For example, if I query `/users/@me/channels` (which is supposed to be the DMs) I get a 401 Unauthorized response from the API. It's the same if I gather a guild id from `/users/@me/guilds` and then try to list the channels in it with `/guilds/guild.id/channels`.

The really weird thing is that I do have all the scopes required (I think so, I didn't take the RPC ones since I don't think it's required for what I want to do) and I can't figure it out myself... What is also weird is that on the OAuth authorization screen, I have those two things:

[image: Read all messages]

[image: This app cannot read messages]

It kind of counterdicts itself... :(

Do you have any ideas you'd like to share ?

Thanks!

Note: I'm using Python but I don't think it's related here, since some endpoints do work with the headers and tokens I have...

Here is my "authentication code":

```
baseUrl = "https://discordapp.com/api"

def authorize():
    scopes = [
        "guilds",
        "email",
        "identify",
        "messages.read",
        "guilds.join",
        "gdm.join",
        "connections"
    ]
    urlAuthorize = "{}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={}&scope={}&response_type=code".format(baseUrl, clientid, ('+'.join(scopes)))
    pyperclip.copy(urlAuthorize)

    code = input("Code: ")
    return code

def getAccessToken(code):
    url = "{}/oauth2/token".format(baseUrl)

    params = {
        "client_id" : clientid,
        "client_secret" : clientsecret,
        "redirect_uri" : "http://localhost",
        "grant_type":"authorization_code",
        "code" : code,
    }

    req = requests.post(url, params = params)
    return json.loads(req.text)
```

And the code related to an API request:

```
def getHeaders():
    return {
        "Authorization" : "{} {}".format("Bearer", config["accessToken"]),
        # "user-agent" : "DiscordBackup/0.0.1"
    } 

def getRequest(endpoint, asJson = True, additional = None):
    url = "{}/{}".format(baseUrl, endpoint)
    req = requests.get(url, headers = getHeaders())
    print()
    print(getHeaders())
    print(url)
    print(req.text)
    if asJson:
        return json.loads(req.text)
    else:
        return req.text

def getMe(): # this works
    endpoint = "users/@me"
    return getRequest(endpoint)

def getMyDMs(): # this gives me a code 401 Unauthorized
    endpoint = "/users/@me/channels"
    return getRequest(endpoint)
```

Comment: Exactly which of the [scopes](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#scopes) does your bot have? It'd also be nice to see some code so we can see if you made a mistake somewhere else.

Comment: I added them, as well as two request functions, one that works and one that gives me a code 401.

Comment: @ThomasKowalski Did you ever get any farther on this? I have a similar issue: OAuth is working and I can read `/users/@me/guilds`, but I can't read `/users/@me/channels`.

Comment: No I did not and gave up. If you ever find a solution, please tell me!

Answer (score 4):

I came across this post when encountering this issue, and to put it bluntly, there's no way to resolve it.

The `messages.read` permission is for a local RPC server; https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#shared-resources-oauth2-scopes

However, local RPC servers are in private beta and you must sign up/get accepted to use this.

I wanted to create a DM exporter, but that doesn't look likely now.

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I wanted to know! Even though the answer arrives pretty late, I'm glad to know it wasn't my code that was wrong

Comment: Yeah, just thought it might be worth mentioning for anyone else that stumbles across this, but I'm glad you're still active and managed to read it :)

My best bet now is to use the bearer tokens, which do obviosuly give you access to DMs, but many people might not want to do this.